# How to convert string from encoding codes to charactes?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text of strings that looks like:

> %D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

How can I convert it to actual characters?
If I'm understand it right it's UTF char codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is URL-encoded:

```
var s = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0");
```

Produces:

> "Строка"

Which is Russian for "row" or "string", I think.

Answer (score 1):

See the accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724862/hex-to-string-c), you just need to change their "-" to your "%"