# SQL Server: Convert image data to string

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to read data from an old application and one of the fields is stored as an image data type in MS SQL Server. I have a feeling it is XML data stored as an image. Any ideas how to convert it?

Here is an example:

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

Comment: If you think it is xml then try converting this to xml.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your string is a flat db record stored as a `hex` data type. If you google 'convert hex to string' and paste in your sample, you will see the record.

What you need to do is convert the string to `byte[]` array, and then you can convert the `byte[]` array into a string.

See the following question for tips on how to do that:
[Converting from hex to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724862/converting-from-hex-to-string)

Cheers!